# Why, after replacing every value in a row, are the first two rows completely different? | Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I've got a simple script to remove characters from the left & right of a string containing a datetime value. The reason for this is that there are unnecessary characters on each side of the actual value I want.

It works by looping through all items in a column (called Time), removing the characters & then replacing the old value with the new one.

This works for the most part, excluding weirdly the first two rows in the dataframe.

For some odd reason, in the .csv files I am using, the 'Time' column has the values as strings, whereas the 'Closing Time' throws an error unless I specify they are strings, even though they have the exact same structure.

Here is a screenshot of what the input fields on the .csv look like:
[image]

Please note: the second row, first value not having a speech mark before it is a weird excel thing & the actual value has it on as seen above in the same screenshot.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv") # reading file

for item in df['Time']:
    item2 = item[1:]
    item3 = item2[:-8]
    df.replace(item, item3, inplace=True)

for item21 in df['Closing Time']:
    item22 = str(item21)[1:]
    item23 = str(item22)[:-8]
    df.replace(item21, item23, inplace=True)

print(df['Closing Time'])
print(df['Time'])

input("\nScript executed successfully | Press ENTER to Exit. ")
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Is this a bug? Because I see no reason why the first two columns specifically are coming out as different to the rest.

Comment: Without seeing the input for the first few rows, there is no way to tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: @9769953 edited post to show input fields of .csv file

Comment: do you want to remove timezones ?

Comment: @Clegane I want to extract the exact date time value without any extra including the timezone. So the value "'2022-11-10 13:52:31 UTC+00'" would become "2022-11-10 13:53:31". The answer below has sorted my issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to extract the timestamps as `string`, I would suggest using regex. Furthermore, iterating over a dataset with a `for` loop is highly inefficient (and with big datasets, you will notice the slowness); I suggest using an `str.extract` function:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv") # reading file

match_string = r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'
df['Time'] = df['Time'].str.extract(match_string)
df['Closing Time'] = df['Closing Time'].str.extract(match_string)

print(df['Closing Time'])
print(df['Time'])

input("\nScript executed successfully | Press ENTER to Exit. ")
```

Comment: I know that for loops are slow for large datasets, but the maximum number of rows I will encounter is 1000 & furthermore I didn't know an alternative. I've pasted your code in & this has worked perfectly. Although, I do not understand it. If you don't mind, what is the "match_string=" line doing?

Comment: match_string is just a regex expresion that matches (in this order):
- 4 digits (year)
- 2 digits (month)
- 2 digits (days)
- 2 digits (hours)
- 2 digits (minutes)
- 2 digits (seconds)
You can play with regex and find more info on regexr.com